# haxm hangs emulator on osx

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, intel

After installing Intel HAXM on my osx 10.6.8, eclipse juno, adt 21.1.0 I am not able to run any of the emulators. The emulator process fries my cpu as in:

[image: excerpt from activity monitor]

where cpu usage never goes below 100%. Yet I have a huge black screen on the emulator.

HAXM extension does not throw any errors. At console, I read

```
[2013-04-02 20:09:58 - myapp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'x86'
[2013-04-02 20:10:03 - Emulator] HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
[2013-04-02 20:10:07 - myapp] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-04-02 20:10:07 - myapp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

I can run the emulators if I remove the HAXM kernel extension. It seems to me that HAXM does not function properly.

Did anyone face the same problem? How can I make emulators run with HAXM installed?

Comment: Run a google search on HAXM patch. Intel released a hotfix which addresses a lot of HAXM issues.

Comment: I upgraded to the latest hotfix. Still no luck.

Comment: Aww, sorry. Fixed it for me, but I'm running 10.8 on retina.

Answer (score 3):

You can try disabling the Hardware Graphics acceleration.

1. Start the AVD Manager
2. Select your AVD instance
3. In the Hardware section: If GPU emulation option is not there, click New, select GPU emulation
4. Change the value to No
5. Start your AVD instance

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been fixed by Intel. If you go to:

[Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager 1.0.6 (R3)](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/)

.. and download and install the item:

> Hotfix for OS X 10.9 only
>
> haxm-macosx_r03_hotfix.zip

.. it now works. I can run nice fast Android emulators on Mac OSX 10.9 without my whole machine freezing.

Comment: You may also need to restart your computer after installing the hotfix to get the emulator to work.

Answer (score 0):

See http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/477793
Intel is aware of it and is looking into it.  Unfortunately, the only workaround is to not use HAXM on OSX Mavericks.

Comment: Intel supports HAXM up to Mac OSX 10.7, according to their instructions at http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x. I confirm that it does not work on 10.9 (freezes the computer). The original question is for 10.6, though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I'm also having this problem lately, running on Windows. How I got by this problem was either:

1. Use an emulator target version 17 or higher.
2. Set up the settings as follows with older emulator target versions:

[image]

[image]

- Make sure you untick "Use Host GPU" and tick "Snapshot"
- Tick "Save to snapshot" on launch options

You don't have to scale it, you can leave that unticked